# os.open() throws IsADirectoryError

Tags: python, python-3.x, chatbot

```
def main():
    chatbot = ChatBot('Bot',
                      storage_adapter ='chatterbot.storage.SQLStorageAdapter',
                      trainer = 'chatterbot.trainers.ListTrainer')
    for files in os.listdir('hector/'):
        convData = open(r'hector/' + files, encoding='latin-1').readlines()
        #convData = open('hector/' + files, 'r').readlines()
        chatbot.set_trainer(ListTrainer)
        chatbot.train(convData)
main()
```

on this hector folder have trainnig text folders, when use os.listdir it's showing this error

```
IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: 'hector/french'
```

Comment: Indentation matters in Python. If you're going to post Python code, please make an effort to reproduce your indentation accurately. If readers have to try and guess your actual indentation, they may miss problems or introduce new ones into the program.

Answer (score 0):

`os.listdir` gives back the names of everthing in the folder: files and subfolders. One of the subfolders of `hector` is `french`. As the error message explains, you can't use `open()` on the folder called `hector\french` (what would it mean if you could?)  Add these lines to your `for` loop, before attempting to open the file:

```
if os.is_dir(files):
    continue
```

so that you don't call `open()` on folders.